# "Hide" li on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qyvhc/7/)

I have in index.html:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" id="Container">
<ul id="my_ul" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-filter-placeholder="Text" data-inset="true">
    <li class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">12</a></li>
    <li class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">123</a></li>
    <li class="ui-screen-hidden"><a href="#">1234</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

js:

```
$("#my_ul li").click(function() {
    $('#Container form input').val($(this).text());
    //$(this).hide();
});
```

So, when I click on li, the text from `li` go to the input. If I use `hide` - that element dont apears, when I delete a sting in input.

I need - click on `li`, text from `li` apears in input, all dropdown `li` hides, but if I deleted string from input, `li` apears.  How to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: +1 for your fiddle :)

Comment: Are you trying to make an autocomplete?

Comment: Your HTML code is invalid. I can see at least 4 errors.

Comment: @Archer yes, I got code over here http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/listviews/

Comment: @Virus721 i know about </a>. Its my mistake

Comment: How do you _hide_ or _delete_ `li` elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this (To hide the list items after selection)

```
$("#my_ul li").click(function() {
    $('#Container form input').val($.trim($(this).text()));
    $('#my_ul').children().addClass('ui-screen-hidden');
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Qyvhc/9/)

Comment: Yes, I can, check the demo.

Answer (score 0):

Hacky solution is to deal with hiding and showing the ul yourself.

Fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Qyvhc/8/

```
$("#my_ul li").click(function() {
    $('#Container form input').val($(this).text());
    $("#my_ul").hide();
});

$('#Container form input').on('focus', function () {
    $("#my_ul").show();    
});
```

I doubt it's the best solution but I can't see anything in the API docs that would achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new into JQuery but hope this is what you wanted.
[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Qyvhc/13/)